# Is there a thumbstick Linux image for checking hardware?

Tags: hardware-failure, linux-distributions, diagnostic

Is there a thumbstick Linux image for checking hardware? Ideally I'd like to take it with me to a second hand shop, boot it up and run a quick round of diagnostics on hardware. It must have both latest NV and AMD drivers, as well as specialized software for detecting if they're damaged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Hiren's BootCD](http://www.hiren.info/pages/bootcd)

I used the included [Video Memory Stress Test](http://mikelab.kiev.ua/index_en.php?page=PROGRAMS/vmt_en) tool to check the video memory on my VAIO laptop after I was getting BSODs. It detected memory faults almost straight away.

It also comes with a great selection of other diagnostic tools.

Comment: Hiren's is impressive.  +1

Comment: That's great, but I'm more concerned about dead or buggy shader units or the number not being up to specs.